# Как отличить одну форму от другой во Flask

Tags: python, flask

У меня есть две формы в html с методами POST.
Во Flask-е же

```
@app.route('/add_article', methods=['POST','GET'])
def add_article():
  if request.methods == 'POST':
     # do smth
```

Чего я хочу, так это то что на странице у меня несколько форм, и надо как то для if-а как то отличить одну форму от другой.

Comment: Добавляйте в форму какое-нибудь дополнительное поле, значение которой позволит понять, какая это форма